# Cron and WP Super Cache in Preload Mode

Tags: cron, plugin-wp-supercache

I disabled WordPress Cron and configured a real Cron (Linux Cron) to hit `wp-cron.php` every 8 hours, but I'm not sure how it affects the behavior of WP Super Cache in Preload Mode.

As far as I know, WP Super Cache processes 100 posts, takes a break of 10 seconds, processes another 100 posts, takes a break of 10 seconds, and so on.

Suppose a website has 10,000 posts. I'm pretty sure the initial 100 posts will be processed the first time `wp-cron.php` is hit, but when will the other posts be processed? Will they wait until the next hit to `wp-cron.php` (+8 hours)?

Answer (score 2):

> Will they wait until the next hit to wp-cron.php (+8 hours)?

Yes.

That's why it's important to keep this duration shorter. I usually keep it to *every 5 minutes*.

PS: I know it's an old question. But, wanted to answer it anyway, if someone else has the same question in the future.